# Error while creating an nsarray from plist?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray

I am trying to create an NSArray from a .plist file, but I keep getting this error:

"`'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSCFString 0x5bbca60> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Value1.'`"

In the .plist file, I have a key called "Item 1" and a string value called "Value1." 
Then in the code I have an NSArray being created from that file:

```
-(void)recordValues:(id)sender {

    // read "propertyList.plist" values
    NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"propertyList" ofType:@"plist"];
    originalArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

   // dump the contents of the array to the log
    for (id key in originalArray) {
        NSLog(@"bundle: key=%@, value=%@", key, [originalArray valueForKey:key]);
    }

    //create an NSMutableArray containing the
    //user's score and the values from originalArray
    NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:userScore], nil];
    [newArray addObjectsFromArray:array];

    //write xml representation of mutableArray back to propertyList
    [newArray writeToFile:plistPath atomically:NO];

}

    }
```

Comment: Truthfully, I just can't tell what you are trying to do.  A bit more precise language, please?

Comment: Sure!  I have a property list which is an array.  These are basically like high scores in a game.  When someone plays the game, I add their scores to a brand new NSMutableArray.  Then I take this new mutable array and combine it with the high scores from my property list, and write the whole collection back to the original plist file.  But I'm getting an error and I don't know why.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I forgot I left one of my old variables in there, which doesn't make sense if you don't know what the app does.  :)  Sorry.  Fixed it.

Comment: FYI, you could simplify your code and use a single variable if you do this: `NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];` As it stands right now, you're leaking `originalArray`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays do not have keys (they don't need any because their elements are addressed by their indices), only dictionaries consist of key-value pairs. Try:

```
for (id value in originalArray) {
            NSLog(@"bundle: value=%@", value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `for` loop, you're using `originalArray` like a dictionary. If the root of your plist is a dictionary, you should use `NSDictionary`, not `NSArray` to read it.

Comment: the root is an NSArray.  How do I read it as an NSArray then?  I need to add values, and I can't add values with an NSDictionary.

Comment: exactly, if the root is "Array", then you can use either NSArray or NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSMutableArray immediately instead of NSArray and convert to NSMutableArray as well be sure that your pList is Array type. Your code would look:

```
-(void)recordValues:(id)sender {
// read "propertyList.plist" values
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"propertyList" ofType:@"plist"];
//create an NSMutableArray containing the
//user's score and the values from originalArray
NSMutableArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile: path];
[newArray addObjectsFromArray:array];
//check-out the content
NSLog(@"The content of the array: %@", array);
//write xml representation of mutableArray back to propertyList
[array writeToFile:plistPath atomically:NO];
}
}
```